# Conversion failed when converting from a character string to a uniqueidentifier while importing table?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, uniqueidentifier, navicat, nul

I'm trying to import a table with Navicat for SQL Server and I get this error:

> [Err] [Row1] [Imp] 42000 - [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
>
> [Err] [Row1] [Imp]

```
INSERT INTO [edfi].[StudentSchoolAssociation] 
       ([StudentUSI],[SchoolId], [SchoolYear],[EntryDate],
        [EntryGradeLevelDescriptorId], [EntryGradeLevelReasonTypeId], 
        [EntryTypeDescriptorId], [RepeatGradeIndicator],
        [SchoolChoiceTransfer], [ExitWithdrawDate], 
        [ExitWithdrawTypeDescriptorId],[ResidencyStatusDescriptorId], 
        [PrimarySchool], [EmployedWhileEnrolled],
        [ClassOfSchoolYear], [EducationOrganizationId], 
        [GraduationPlanTypeDescriptorId], [GraduationSchoolYear],
        [Id], [LastModifiedDate], [CreateDate]) 
VALUES ('89', '2', 
        '2014', '1913-9-9', 
        '133', NULL, 
        '2184038928404', NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '1776',
        '', 0, 0)
```

> [Err] [Row1] [Imp] 42000 - [SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

The third to last column is `ID`, which is a NOT NULL uniqueidentifier with (`newid()`). I want to autogenerate these ID's, so they are empty in the csv file.

Comment: If you want to use the defined default value, then you must **omit** the `ID` column from your `INSERT` statement - in that case, SQL Server will fill in the default value. If you provide a value (even `NULL` or an empty string `''`), SQL Server will use *that value provided*

Comment: You're right. Thanks!